# Monitor GPS status(can't check it if user turns GPS off using Notification Bar)

Tags: android, android-location

In my app I need to **monitor GPS status**, app should only run with GPS on and if user turns GPS off, I show "Location and security" settings. I've implemented custom class for GPS monitoring:

```
public class GPSManager {
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    StatusListener statusListener;


    /**
     * @param Context context - context to get LocationManager service
     * @param IGpsStatusClient client -component, which wants to receive GPS status update
     */
    public GPSManager(Context context, IGpsStatusClient client) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        statusListener=new StatusListener(client);
    }

    public boolean isGpsEnabled(){
        return mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    public void registerUpdates() {
        mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(statusListener);
    }

    public void unregisterUpdates() {
       mLocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(statusListener);
    }

    class StatusListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {

        IGpsStatusClient client;

        public StatusListener(IGpsStatusClient client){
            this.client=client;
        }

        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            if(event==GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED){
                client.promptGpsSettings();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Client here is a Fragment class instance. It implements IGpsStatusClient interface, with one method(in which I show location settings).
I register updates in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()`
But this has no effect. When I expand Notification Bar and turn GPS off and then return to app, no prompt is shown. As I understand, GPS status notification is not like a 'pending intent', which hangs for a while, so that all receivers can process it. 
What are the options? 
As I understand, **GPS could be turned off only by user, NOT while my Activity is visible.** So, I only should check GPS status in Activity(or Fragment) lifecycle events. But when notification bar is expanded, I don't get onResume() or onPause() calls(But then why I don't receive GPS status notification?)
I was thinking about Service, but think it's expensive for my problem.
Any help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried implementing `LocationListener` and using the `onProviderDisabled`/`onProviderEnabled` methods?

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) is a link to the android developer page about `LocationListener`